# OpenCV create an object mask from incomplete contours in android

Tags: android, opencv

I am working with OpenCV for android and trying to create a shape mask from the found contours.
I have found contours of an object using findContours of only external contours, such as:

[Contours of a fork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Gsp.png)

I want to create a mask in order to seperate the object from the background. For the example of the fork, it should be something like this:

[Desired mask for the fork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mfRk.png)

I tried to use fillPoly to accomplish it, but the problem is that the contours are not connected.

I also tried to connect them into one contour but the connections are not right.
Is there a way to get the general shape of the contours and create this mask?

Thanks.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21469409/2436175), you can get some hints from the comments there.

Comment: Try to apply some filtering on the image before finding the contour, such as Canny edge detection. You need to have this contour whole. After that, check [this](http://www.bytefish.de/blog/extracting_contours_with_opencv/) article

Comment: I have edge detection with Canny before finding the contours. I also already tried to use approxPolyDP to have the polygon of the shape. Thanks